Issue with Python application after deploying using Azure DevOps
Facing an issue deploying a Python application using Azure DevOps pipeline to Azure App Service.
Tried both Docker image and zip deploy but resulted in the same error.
App service plan is Linux. Deployment is successful but I get gateway time out in browser "504.0 Gateway Timeout".
Gateway Error:

The python app runs fine locally and I am able to publish  to Azure App Service using VS Code.
Have updated app settings by adding WEBSITES_PORT key and tried with 8000, 8080 & 5000 port number with no luck.
Logs from log stream:

Here's the docker File:


Deploy a minimal hello world sample (return "hello") and share us if the error is the same. Also share the sample code.

Please post the code and error messages as text, not images.

Based on the description so far, I could only reproduce similar issues when my app container failed to run/start. There could be many different errors that failed containers from starting, while a pipeline run could be succeeded since it simply set the configurations but didn't wait for the container to start.

You may leverage the app Advanced tools to check the container logs and sort out the actual error.

Here is my updated sample for your reference based on the simple demo in this document, together with my YAML pipeline definition.
Updated Dockerfile
# Pull a pre-built alpine docker image with nginx and python3 installed
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.8-alpine-2020-12-19

# Set the port on which the app runs; make both values the same.
#
# IMPORTANT: When deploying to Azure App Service, go to the App Service on the Azure 
# portal, navigate to the Applications Settings blade, and create a setting named
# WEBSITES_PORT with a value that matches the port here (the Azure default is 80).
# You can also create a setting through the App Service Extension in VS Code.
ENV LISTEN_PORT=5000
EXPOSE 5000

# Indicate where uwsgi.ini lives
ENV UWSGI_INI uwsgi.ini

# Tell nginx where static files live. Typically, developers place static files for
# multiple apps in a shared folder, but for the purposes here we can use the one
# app's folder. Note that when multiple apps share a folder, you should create subfolders
# with the same name as the app underneath "static" so there aren't any collisions
# when all those static files are collected together.
ENV STATIC_URL /hello_app/static

# Set the folder where uwsgi looks for the app
WORKDIR /hello_app

# Copy the app contents to the image
COPY . /hello_app

# If you have additional requirements beyond Flask (which is included in the
# base image), generate a requirements.txt file with pip freeze and uncomment
# the next three lines.
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt


azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  # ACR
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'ACRSvcCnnWIF'
  imageRepository: 'containerapp/python/flask'
  containerRegistry: 'azacrxxxxxx.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: $(Build.BuildId)

  # Azure Web App for container
  ARMSvcCnn: ARMSvcCnnWIFAutoSub1
  webAppName: azwebapp-xxxxxx-python-container

stages:
- stage: CI_BuildPushACRImage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildPushACRImage
    displayName: Build
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

- stage: CD_DeployAzureWebAppContainer
  dependsOn: CI_BuildPushACRImage
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployAzureWebAppContainer
    environment: E-AzureWebAppContainer
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
              appName: '$(webAppName)'
              containers: '$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'
              appSettings: >
                -DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD $(DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD)
                -DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME $(DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME)
                -DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL https://$(containerRegistry)
                -WEBSITES_PORT 5000



Thank you, will try this out and get back

Hi @vikkz, You may begin with the sample code in the document and my pipeline in the answer for a test. Hope it works for your app as well. Thx for the efforts and wish you a lovely weekend.
